# surfaceview + buttons findviewbyid returns null

Tags: android, surfaceview, findviewbyid

My code is ok but unfortunately my code gives me null pointer exception. I know that by writing the setcontentview before findviewbyid it wont happen but then by doing so my surface does not update.I tried lot searching about this but i am not able to get proper answer for this please help me.My code for mainctivity:-

```
package com.example.snakes;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

MySurfaceClass sc;
Button up,down,left,right;
//View v1,v2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    sc = new MySurfaceClass(this);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    down = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    up.setOnClickListener(this);
    down.setOnClickListener(this);
    left.setOnClickListener(this);
    right.setOnClickListener(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Toast.makeText(this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
        sc.posY = sc.posY - 50 ;
        Toast.makeText(this, "up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //   sc = new MySurfaceClass(this);
      //   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        sc.posY = sc.posY + 50 ;
        Toast.makeText(this, "down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // sc = new MySurfaceClass(this);
         //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        break;

    case R.id.button3:
        sc.posX = sc.posX - 50 ;
        Toast.makeText(this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //sc = new MySurfaceClass(this);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        break;

    case R.id.button4:
        sc.posX = sc.posX + 10 ;
        Toast.makeText(this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

while the code for surface activity:-

```
package com.example.snakes;


public class MySurfaceClass extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

private SurfaceHolder sh;
private Thread t = null;
private boolean isRunning;
private Bitmap b;
protected int posX, posY;

public MySurfaceClass(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MySurfaceClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MySurfaceClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

void init() {
    isRunning = true;
    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.face);
    posX = 0;
    posY = 0;
    sh = this.getHolder();
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
};

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100, null);
}

public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        if (!sh.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

        Canvas c = sh.lockCanvas();
        c.drawRGB(5, 150, 10);
        c.drawBitmap(b, posX, posY, null);
        sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
}
  }
```

and the xml :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/grey"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="up" 
        android:layout_weight="25"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="down" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="right" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.snakes.MySurfaceClass
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: "My code is ok but unfortunately my code gives me null pointer exception" - then it rather means your code is not OK, isn't it? :)

Comment: well ya sorry for that but thats because if i write setcontentview before then it does not give error thats why

Comment: So fix your SurfaceView class, as you clearly got problems there.

Comment: but i am not able to figure out how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**setContentView** method has to be called before getting any references to widgets with **findViewById** otherwise you will get NullPointerExceptions when setting the click listeners to the buttons.

I would make the buttons work first, then worry about the surface view.

Comment: but the buttons work properly but the view is not getting updated if i did setcontentview before findviewbyid

Comment: Yeah that's the point. You HAVE to call setContentView before getting the buttons references, otherwise you will get NPE's. In relation to the SurfaceView, it doesn't look like you are getting it from the content view using findViewById, but you are actually instantiating a new one.

Comment: yes so then once i instantiate it the thread starts and as i am changing the position values the surfaceview should get updated but i does not why is it so ?

Comment: Well you should start your thread on the activity onResume method, and not at the instantiation. Specially, because if you inflate a layout with your custom surface view in it, the layout inflater will instantiate all views, meaning that you don't have control over it. Do this, remove the instantiation line. Get the sc reference with the findViewById method. Move your SurfaceView start code to a different method. Call the start method from the activity onResume

Comment: but there is no onResume methoo for surfaceclass should i use it in main activity class ?

Comment: Correct. The view is defined within an activity. The activity should control the views. If you have a long runnig thread in your SurfaceView you should have methods to start and stop that thread when the view is not displayed. This start/stop methods, should be called from the ACtivity onResume/onPause methods.

Comment: Looking into it twice, you do have an init() method that is not being called from anywhere. Call it from the Activity.onResume method. And add a method to stop the thread and deallocate all the thread resources, and call it from the onPause

Comment: and after doing this onreusume and onpause thing now should I instantiate sc or do by findviewbyid

Comment: findViewById. I would recommend you to read the activity lifecycle documentation, since it's important to know how to handle it correctly. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: sc =  findViewById(R.id.surfaceView); I do gave sc the reference by findviewbyid but then how could i call the methods in resume and pause without using the varible of other class?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is broken. You HAVE TO `setContentView()` otherwise there's no view attached.

Comment: but i have set the content view

Comment: Nope. You got this commented out -> `//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: ok now if i write setContentView before then the app runs but the surface is not updated